# Is __block keyword needed for writing for in loop in objective C when mutating an array or dictionary?

Tags: objective-c

Is __block keyword needed for writing for in loop in objective C when mutating an array or dictionary?

```
__block NSMutableArray *xxxx = [NSMutableArray new]; // is __block needed?
for (obj in objs) {
    [xxx addObject];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. The `__block` keyword is needed only when several conditions are met:

- There is an Objective-C "block" — a segment of code captured as an object, and
- There is a variable declared outside the block, and
- The value of the variable is changed inside the block

This might be clearer by counterexample. Where *don't* you need the `__block` keyword?

You don't need it when your loop is a simple C loop, including plain `for` loops and loops that use NSFastEnumeration:

```
NSInteger sum = 0;
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    sum += i; // okay! this is a plain C for loop
}

NSArray *numbers = @[@1, @2, @3];
for (NSNumber *i in numbers) {
    sum += [i integerValue]; // okay! this is an NSFastEnumeration object loop
}
```

When you have an actual Objective-C block, you don't need it if the body of the block doesn't really mutate the value of the variable. This is often the case if your block only sends Objective-C messages to an object:

```
NSMutableArray *evenNumbers = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *numbers = @[@1, @2, @3];
[numbers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    if ([obj integerValue] % 2 == 0) {
        [evenNumbers addObject:obj]; // okay! this is an ObjC message send, which does not mutate the pointer value of `evenNumbers`
    }
}];
```

The only case you need it is when your block intends to mutate the value of a variable directly.

```
__block NSString *match = nil;
__block NSUInteger matchIndex = NSNotFound;
NSArray *candidates = @[@"foo", @"bar"];
[candidates enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    if ([obj isEqual:@"foo"]) {
        // these must be __block, because we are mutating their values in this ObjC block
        match = obj;
        matchIndex = idx;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

No. `__block` is needed if value of variable is changed inside block, eg.

```
__block NSUInteger sum = 0;
[objs enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:
^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    sum += obj.number; // just imaginary
}];
```

in your case value of variable is pointer and it is not changed.

Comment: Deleting my comment because it no longer applies to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, in the code snippet you've posted you don't need `__block` modifier.